# Ionic 4 Push Notification

Tags: push-notification, ionic4, angular8

I am getting an issue with sound in push notification
Using Ionic 4 and Angular 8 to creating android app

My code to send Push in PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => $_POST['message'],
    'title'     => $_POST['title'],
    'subtitle'  => $_POST['subtitle'],
    'tickerText' => $_POST['ticket_text'],
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'alert'=> 'true',
    'badge'=> true,
    'sound'=> 'true',
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'              => $msg
);
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
```

and the config.xml file for android platform

```
<platform name="android">

        <resource-file src="resources/android/push.mp3" target="res/push.mp3" />
    </platform>
```